# Countifs formula not working when data is in different sheet

Tags: excel

I want a total count of all employees where department i.e. column B7 matches with the department in another sheet i.e. Associates covered and tenure should be greater then 60

I tried using below formula but it is reflecting as `#VALUE`. Please assist

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B7,'Associates Covered'!$D$3:$D$522,'Associates Covered'!$D$3:$D$522,"<60"))
```

Comment: Check the syntax of [countifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) B7 is not a column, it’s a cell. First argument in formula is a range. And without seeing the data, it’s difficult to tell, but why are you wrapping the function with sumproduct?

Comment: You got the criteriarange and criteria swapped, but why would you check the same range for different values? It's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Your logic flow is slightly off.

Your first `Countif` criteria tests cell B7 against a range in a different sheet. This cannot be done without an array formula, as you cannot test if a single cell matches a range this way, you have to test what in the range matches this cell. Therefore your `Countifs` should start like:

```
COUNTIFS('Associates Covered'!$D$3:$D$522, B7
```

This will resolve your `#VALUE` error.

Secondly, the second `Countif` criteria might be off, as it tests the same range (D3 to D522) to be "<60", this would never change the result, since if the first evaluates to false the second isn't even considered, and for the second one to be true, the first one would always have to be true regardless, making it redundant.

Comment: This is not actually correct. You can indeed test one cell against a range of values, and get back an array of results (hence the SUMPRODUCT). It is not, however, clear if that's what the poster intended!

Comment: @Rory you are correct, if an array formula was intended, this is definitely incorrect. We would need much more detail to answer OP and evaluate his requirements, as for now he stated the issue was getting `#value` results, which my answer will resolve.

Comment: It was more the fact that your answer says "this cannot be done" when it clearly can. :)

Comment: @Rory I have edited my answer so that your point is also highlighted and should be slightly clearer.